# Pronunciation of final sound -ge

Tags: pronunciation

Can we ignore the final sound -ge as speaking the following sentence?
"Having true consciousness can change someone's life."

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot ignore that sound. The -ge is not a separate syllable. Instead, it adds a "dj" sound to the end of the word. If you leave off the "dj" sound, then you have the sound of "chain", which is a different word, and that makes the sentence not make sense.